# Path Regular Expression - Allow only one level

Tags: php, regex

I would like a regular expression that matches the following:

```
/home
/news
/blog
/home/
/news/
/blog/
```

However, it shouldn't match:

```
/product/logs/barbeque
/product/1
/blog/post/1
```

`/home` and such are *not fixed* - it should match that *structure* of the URL

Comment: Your question boggles and confuses me. It also frightens and annoys me. More specific, please?

Comment: @Andrew +1 for a hilarious multitude of emotions :)

Comment: @Pekka - Maybe I overdid the coffee this morning? ;)

Comment: @Andrew that would explain confused, frightened, and annoyed, but not *boggled*. I think you need something stronger for boggled. Maybe somebody spiked it? :)

Comment: Can't understand your question either.

Comment: "and no the /home etc" is probably "and note that /home etc". Strange, but I have made this typo multiple times myself.

Comment: @JP19 yeah, me too. I've found myself typing "mysql" instead of "myself". Slightly frightening as well :)

Comment: @Pekka - what, you mean you haven't achieved one-ness with the database yet?

Comment: @Andrew not yet. But I can hear C, Java and PHP apart by their taste. That took some training, they taste very similar because of the many brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the question is presented, this ought to do:

```
#^/[^/]+$#
```

This will match anything starting with a forward slash (`/`) and then at least one character (which *cannot* be a `/`), e.g., `/home`, `/news`, and `/blog`.

`/product/logs/barbeque`, `/product/1`, and `/blog/post/1` will all fail on the "cannot be a `/`" part.

---

**UPDATE**
As for the updated matches `/home/`, `/news/`, and `/blog/`, consider this:

```
#^/[^/]+/?$#
```

Comment: Is this the emoticon illustrating Andrew's comment above? :)

Comment: @Pekka Could be :) Legend: `#^/[^/]+$#`: Confused, frightened, annoyed, and boggled.

Comment: @user393273 Add parentheses if you need to match the `home` part, e.g., `#^/([^/]+)/?$#`.

Comment: What a Picasso-esque emoticon.

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do.

If you're searching for specific words in the URL, why not use string comparison functions directly? For the second set of URLs (which you don't want to match), regex is preferable.

However, in your case you'll be better off using [strcmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) and friends directly.