# PHP Regex Pattern - Match url if only one level deep

Tags: php, regex

My question is similar to this but I can't get it to work: [Path Regular Expression - Allow only one level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553686/path-regular-expression-allow-only-one-level)

I have an array with a bunch or urls from a website that are either a category or sub-category page so:

```
http://www.mysite.com/dogs/
http://www.mysite.com/cats/
http://www.mysite.com/food/
```

are category pages (only level beyond the root domain)

Sub-category pages look like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/dogs/poodles/
http://www.mysite.com/cats/siamese/
http://www.mysite.com/food/pizza/
```

I want to strip out the sub-categories and only be left with category pages in the array.  Any url that contains anything beyond the first set of / / after the root url should be filtered out.

I think I need to use preg_grep but using the pattern in the updated answer that I referenced above like

```
$regex = "#^/[^/]+/?$#";    
$categories_only = preg_grep($regex,$array);
```

yields an empty array.

What pattern will match this correctly?

Comment: Do you _really_ need to use regex?

Comment: Not at all.  How else can I filter out the sub-category urls that I don't need?

Comment: Do your URLs start with "/" or with "http://"?  "^/" would match a slash at the beginning of the string, no?  What about this? #^http://[^/]+/?[^/]+$#

Comment: they start do start with http://www.mysite.com.  okay, not really mysite.com.

Comment: @quasivivo $regex = "#^http://[^/]+/?[^/]+$#"; did not work.

Comment: See updated answer below.  I didn't account for the trailing slashes on your root category URLs.  "#^http://[^/]+/?[^/]+/?$#"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you don't need regex for this task.
You could implement a function to filter the array:

```
$urls = array('http://www.mysite.com/dogs/',
        'http://www.mysite.com/cats/siamese/junk/?trash=1&x=y',
        'http://www.mysite.com/food/pizza/');

function filter_url($url) {
    $split = explode('/', $url);
    return (count($split) == 5 && empty($split[4])) || 
           (count($split) == 4 && !empty($split[3]));
}

print_r(array_filter($urls, 'filter_url'));
```

This would output:

```
Array ( [0] => http://www.mysite.com/dogs/ )
```

Comment: I am starting out with an array and want to be left with an array that only contains categories.  I'm not seeing how this will do this?  I could try to play with this a bit though.  Thank you.

Comment: @ErikBerger I have edited the answer. With this version, you should use `array_filter` to filter your array with a function that verifies if the url has only the category. Like in this example, the only url matched was the first.

Comment: This is a cleaner solution, but as is it won't return pages without a trailing slash: "http://www.mysite.com/cats"

Comment: @quasivivo: Yeah, but it is pretty straightforward to figure out. I think the point was to show the `array_filter` function which was made  exactly for what he was looking for.

Comment: @murilo-vasconcelos Agreed, and it is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

This outputs:

Array
(
    [2] => http://www.mysite.com/dogs/
    [3] => http://www.mysite.com/cats/
    [4] => http://www.mysite.com/food/
)

```
<?php
$array = array("http://www.mysite.com/dogs/poodles/",
"http://www.mysite.com/cats/siamese/",
"http://www.mysite.com/dogs/",
"http://www.mysite.com/cats/",
"http://www.mysite.com/food/",
"http://www.mysite.com/food/pizza/");

$regex = "#^http://[^/]+/?[^/]+/?$#";

$categories_only = preg_grep($regex,$array);

print_r($categories_only);
```

Comment: I see that this contained php example works perfectly in php sandbox:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ but for some reason I couldn't get it to work on the real server.  Could it be because of the slashes not being escaped?

Comment: @erik-berger I've never had trouble with forward slashes inside of RegEx with "#" delimiters, but you might try putting single quotes around the regex string to prevent all possible internal interpolation.  $regex = '#^http://[^/]+/?[^/]+/?$#';

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})\/([\da-z\.-]+)\/
```

It only allows for two forward slashes after the .com or whatever.
play here... http://rubular.com/r/TBLpnJFdJg